# Stop Excel 365 from automatically building a query on import

Tags: microsoft-excel

How can I stop Excel 365 from automatically building a query when I import a external data file? I simply want the data in columns without active headers or other formatting. I'm looking for an import logic like older Excel releases without automatically formatting.

**CVS File Import**

```
Bob,Brown,123,-23.43  
Mike,White,456,45  
Barb,Grey,789,33.33
```

**Should Import As**

```
     A        B            C       D
1    Bob      Brown        123     -23.43
2    Mike     White        456     45
3    Barb     Grey         789     33.33
```

Comment: Add **From TEXT(Legacy)** option to new group in Ribbon from File- Options- Customize Ribbon.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the Power Query (Get & Transform) import, you can use the legacy tools, but you need to activate them first.

Go File > Options > Data. In the section "Show legacy data import wizards" select "From Text (Legacy)" and any other legacy wizard you may want to use.

Close the Options.

On the Data ribbon, click Get Data > Legacy Wizards > From Text.

The Legacy Wizards option will only show if you have at least one of the legacy wizards enabled as described above.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. If that helped solve your issue, please finish the paperwork and accept the answer as explained in the [tour].